# ListPopupWindow does not react on click events when it is not modal

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

I have attached a TextWatcher to an EditText component in my application, and are calling this after the text has changed; (mListPopupWindow is ListPopupWindow)

```
mListPopupWindow = new ListPopupWindow(getActivity());
mListPopupWindow.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mListPopupWindow.setContentWidth(400);
mListPopupWindow.setAnchorView(mRootView);
mListPopupWindow.setModal(false);
mListPopupWindow.setOnItemClickListener(MyFragment.this 
mListPopupWindow.setOnDismissListener(MyFragment.this);
mListPopupWindow.show();
```

The OnClick event that is present in my fagment gets the OnClick event if the popup is constructed with setModel(true). It does not get the Onclick event if the popup is not modal.

I am using this View to create a Suggest Box that change the contents of the popup list based on what the user is typing in the EditText. If I set the popup window to modal, the Edittext component loses focus every time the user enters a new letter into the EditText. That is very uncool :-)

Can anyone explain how to get Click events when the ListPopupWindow is not modal, or how else to construct a "suggest" list below an EditText View?

Comment: This question is no longer relevant. I was trying to achieve the same an AutocompleteTextView. I did not know that such a view existed, and tried to roll my own. See here for how it workds:  http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-autocomplete.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is no longer relevant. I was trying to achieve the same an AutocompleteTextView. I did not know that such a view existed, and tried to roll my own.